# Why am I seeing this character in Neovim?'

Tags: neovim, wsl

I copy pasted [init.lua](https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim/blob/master/init.lua) from Neovim kickstarter.

Now while writing c++ code I am getting the below '?' character inside a box in Neovim

[image]

I am using Neovim in Ubuntu subsystem windows 10.

I think some character not supported in WSL, maybe.

Comment: Is you move your cursor on the character and hit `ga` what is the message you get? What is the result od the `:set listchars?` command?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? How can we help you further?

Comment: `ga` gives Null and
`:set listchars?` gives `, trail:-, nbsp:+`

Comment: Thanks. Could you precise what you mean by "give Null". For a Null character I have in the message area the following text: `<^@>  0,   Hex 00, Octal 000`. If I hit `g8` I have `00`. Could you tell me what exact text you have?

Comment: Can you tell us what is the result of the `:set list?` command? Is the result of `ga` and `g8` the same for the first line character and the second line character?

Comment: Do you confirm that `:set listchars?` result contains a leading `,` and that it contains space? Do you confirm the result?

Comment: `:set listchars?` gives `nolist` and `ga` / `g8` gives `NUL` in message when I put the commands for `?` character i.e the tab

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `tab` part of your `listchars` option is set to a character that is not supported by your console font.

You could change that characters or characters using:

```
:set listchars^=-->
```

More information with: `:help 'listchars'`.

Of course you could also change the console font and select a font that support that character (Consolas is a standard choice).

Answer (score 0):

Used these below config lines in init.lua to get it resolved.

```
local o = vim.opt
-- Set your characters here
o.listchars = { space = ' ', tab = '| ' }
o.list = true
o.relativenumber = true
```